# Repeat a div number of times

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to repeat a div X times over html page,
lets say I want to set variance to declare times of repeat.
repeat this section 5 times, I assume it's with JS.

```
<div class="blackstrip">black</div>
<div class="bluestrip">
    BLUE
    <div class="whitestrip">WHITE strip</div>
</div>
```

I'm adding the css as it comes out strange look -

```
.blackstrip{
opacity: 0.8;
width: 600px;
height: 100px;
background-color: black;
background-position: center;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

```
.bluestrip{
opacity: 0.5;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
background-color: blue;
background-repeat: none;
padding-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
margin-top:50px;
margin: 20px auto;
```

}

```
.whitestrip{
opacity: 0.8;
width: 100px;
height:300px;
background-color: gray;
position: relative;
float: right;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Use a templating language with a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a for loop eg:

```
var amount = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    var new_div = document.createElement("div");
    new_div.className = "bluestrip";
    document.body.appendChild(new_div);
    console.log("This is repeat " + i);
}
```

> Simple technic, huh?

https://jsfiddle.net/d15e9r6z/

*Like Andreas said, it is more effective if you use*
[DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/DocumentFragment) *to change multiple DOM's.*

Comment: Use a [`DocumentFragement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) so you only have to change the DOM once instead of `amount` times

Comment: Added this as option. Thank you.

Comment: @Maurice Okay it works but not completely. when you try to repeat the 3 divs it doesn't show well. how do you add to new_div.className = 3 of the divs

Comment: no, you don't add divs with className. You have to createElement for each. appendChild them to the right parent and className them right.

Comment: Okay got you. still the whitestripe div defined as inner div in Blue strip (floating right on screen), define this.

Comment: Works like magik, for this reason -  
 new_div_3.className = "whitestrip";    new_div_2.appendChild(new_div_3);